# JMeter JMS Publisher error when trying to publish to ActiveMQ Artemis queue: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.jms.Message.setJMSDeliveryTime(J)V

Tags: jmeter, activemq-artemis

On a Windows 10 machine with Java 11.0.21. I have downloaded a fresh latest version of JMeter 5.6.3.

I have a jmx file with a JMS Publisher Sampler which is configured to connect and publish to a queue running on a remote ActiveMQ Artemis server.

I am using `activemq-all-5.18.3.jar` in order for the JMS Publisher Sampler to be able to communicate with the remote ActiveMQ Artemis queue.

The `activemq-all-5.18.3.jar` is placed it in a `Dependencies` folder on my local path and I load it to the classpath through a `config.properties` file:

```
user.classpath=./Dependencies
```

The config file is invoked like this:

```bash
$ jmeter -q .\config.properties -t .\test.jmx
```

Once the GUI launches, I run the test and get the following error in the JMeter log:

```
ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Create 1-1,6,main]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.jms.Message.setJMSDeliveryTime(J)V
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.send(ActiveMQSession.java:1993) ~[activemq-all-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:329) ~[activemq-all-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:289) ~[activemq-all-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducer.send(ActiveMQMessageProducer.java:224) ~[activemq-all-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.send(ActiveMQMessageProducerSupport.java:298) ~[activemq-all-5.18.3.jar:5.18.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.Publisher.setPropertiesAndSend(Publisher.java:191) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.Publisher.publish(Publisher.java:148) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.PublisherSampler.sample(PublisherSampler.java:233) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.BaseJMSSampler.sample(BaseJMSSampler.java:98) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

I want to be able to Publish the message using the JMS Publisher sampler.

I've tried changing the jar dependency version to a the current latest one (`activemq-all-6.1.0.jar`) and got a different error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/activemq/jndi/ActiveMQInitialContextFactory has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:555) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:458) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:452) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:451) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398) ~[?:?]
    at java.naming/com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper.loadClass(VersionHelper.java:127) ~[?:?]
    at java.naming/com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper.loadClass(VersionHelper.java:133) ~[?:?]
    at java.naming/com.sun.naming.internal.VersionHelper.loadClass(VersionHelper.java:100) ~[?:?]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getFactory(NamingManager.java:757) ~[?:?]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.lambda$getInitialContext$1(NamingManager.java:722) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue$Memoizer.get(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:329) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.AbstractClassLoaderValue.computeIfAbsent(AbstractClassLoaderValue.java:205) ~[?:?]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:722) ~[?:?]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305) ~[?:?]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236) ~[?:?]
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:208) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.InitialContextFactory.lookupContext(InitialContextFactory.java:66) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.InitialContextFactory.getContext(InitialContextFactory.java:155) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.Publisher.<init>(Publisher.java:126) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.PublisherSampler.initClient(PublisherSampler.java:185) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.PublisherSampler.sample(PublisherSampler.java:209) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.BaseJMSSampler.sample(BaseJMSSampler.java:98) ~[ApacheJMeter_jms.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.6.3]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

Does anyone have any idea what the cause is and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the OpenWire JMS client that ships with ActiveMQ *Classic*. Version 5.18.3 doesn't support the JMS 2 method [`javax.jms.Message.setJMSDeliveryTime()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSDeliveryTime-long-) which is why you're hitting the `NoSuchMethodError`. Version 6.0.1 requires Java 17 or higher which is why you're hitting the `UnsupportedClassVersionError`.

I recommend you use the Core JMS client that ships with ActiveMQ Artemis. It fully supports JMS 2 and doesn't require Java 17. It only requires Java 11. If you're downloading it and dropping it into the JMeter classpath I recommend [this one](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/artemis-jms-client-all/2.32.0/).

Comment: Thanks. When using the recommended `artemis-jms-client-all-2.32.0.jar`, I am indeed able to get past the initial error message, but now the JMS Publisher sampler throws this error:
`javax.naming.NamingException: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory]
 at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms.client.InitialContextFactory.lookupContext(InitialContextFactory.java:68)...`
Any idea what else I'm missing?

Comment: You've specified the use of `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory` for JNDI _somewhere_ - either in the JMeter sampler configuration or perhaps in a `jndi.properties` file that's on the classpath. You need to find wherever you've specified that class and change it to be `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`.

Comment: Indeed, your comment was spot-in! Both the JMS Publisher and the JMS Subscriber have a property named Initial Context Factory. That needed to be changed from `org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory` to `org.apache.activemq.artemis.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory`; The script initially used to work without this change, but on a different machine which was running openjdk `21.0.1`. Now that I changed the machine and the java version to 11, I needed to adapt both this property and the used dependency jar. Many thanks for your insightful comments!